# (Beginner Java) Python time.sleep() equivalent in Java? Google says Thread.sleep() for multi-threaded stuff, but trying that throws an error

Tags: java

I'm working on an example in Daniel Liang's *Introduction to Java*, and I'm trying to step through the problem to see what exactly is happening, but everything prints out too quickly. So, I'm looking for an equivalent in Java to Python's time.sleep().

I know I could make a timer via `currentTimeMillis`, but a simple sleep function would be much more handy.

I've tried typing `Thread.sleep(millis)` as suggested on google -- as well as `Thread.getCurrentThread.sleep()`, but both are giving the following error:

> error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or
>   declared to be thrown
>                 Thread.sleep(1000);

This is the piece of code in question:

```
        for (int j = i; j<100; j+=i){

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(j);

        }
```

Comment: The error seems pretty explicit.  Catch the exception in a `try/catch` block or declare the exception thrown in your function declaration.

Comment: Yep, google the Java exceptions tutorial, and believe the error messages when you get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the Thread.sleep inside try catch block like

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   }catch(InterruptedException e){
   }
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The main reason is `Thread.sleep` can be interrupted, this provides with the ability to determine the sleep cycle completed by itself or was interrupted by another thread

Comment: Warning, bad habits! (1) You should catch the most specific exception you can -- in this case, `InterruptedException` (not `Exception`). (2) You should almost never swallow exceptions silently. If you're going to not rethrow, at least re-set the thread's interrupted flag via `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`. That way, whoever instantiated the thread has a chance to deal with the interrupt. Probably not significant if your case is simple, but it's a good habit to get into. Silently swallowing exceptions can get you into problems down the line.

Comment: And you don't have to take my word on it: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html (search for "Don't swallow interrupts")